# Why textcontent is not working in Fire Fox?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox

I am trying to get `textContent` of an element by getting its client ID but its not working :

```
if (document.getElementById('<%=textbox.ClientID%>').textContent) {
    alert("FF");
}
```

Alert is not working in Fire fox.

textbox is `HTMLTextAreaElement`

Comment: Is the element loaded at the time the script is executed?

Comment: @Konstantin Dinev yes element is already loaded before its execution

Comment: What are you getting when you debug this. Is the element retrieved correctly and what does .textContent give you?

Comment: @AlexK. @Konstantin Dinev Please check my updated question element is `HTMLTextAreaElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textarea` element doesn't have `textContent`. Retrieve its `value` instead.

```
if (document.getElementById('<%=textbox.ClientID%>').value)
```

Comment: @aa003 value would be consistent across all browsers.